# Why are docker container's filesystems smaller than their images?

Tags: docker

I am new to using Docker, so this may seem like a silly question, but I just can't figure it out. I already learned that docker images contain the zipped libraries and dependencies needed to run the application, and that containers are created from these images.

However, what I don't understand is how this zipped code in the image is finally executed inside the container. In previous research I found that the containers contain copies of this code in their filesystem and that they add a write layer to this code in order to be runnable. That is why I find it strange to see that in practice images take much more storage than the entire filesystem of the containers based on them. You would expect that since the containers have the unzipped code in their filesystem, these containers would be much larger than their images.

Probably, I am completely misunderstanding how docker works, but can someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you measuring the image vs. container size?  Do you have a [mcve]?  This seems like it might be a little more a question about Docker or Unix filesystem mechanics than about programming _per se_, and another site like [unix.se] might be a more appropriate place to ask.

Comment: You're right, I put the same question over there. Thanks!

Comment: Cross posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750779/where-is-the-actual-executable-program-code-located-in-the-docker-architecture

Answer (score 3):

Containers don't contain copy of the image file system.

Docker is based on a so named **overlay file system** which is a **copy-on-write file system**.

In other words your container starts using merged layers file system  (no more disk space is used), then for each file changed by the running container is written into a new layer, which is in size equal to the sum of the size of the changed files.

Here is [in depth explanation of this concept](https://gdevillele.github.io/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/):

[image: Overlay file system]